# Azure Application Insights not logging Users / Sessions but logging PageViews

Tags: win-universal-app, azure-application-insights

I have an UWP app that is connected to Azure Application Insights.

The Azure interface correctly displays Custom Events but all information about users or sessions is missing.

[image: No users or sessions]

I think the PageViews are being logged because I added the custom code:

```
App.Telemetry.TrackPageView("PageViewName");
```

edit:
I'm initializing the Telemetry with:

```
WindowsAppInitializer.InitializeAsync("-code-",
WindowsCollectors.Metadata | WindowsCollectors.PageView | 
WindowsCollectors.Session | WindowsCollectors.UnhandledException);
```

I also have the following (redundant?) initializers:

```
Telemetry.InstrumentationKey = "-code-;
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = "-code-";
Telemetry.Context.InstrumentationKey = "-code-";
```

end_edit

Is there anything that I'm missing?
I seem to recall that in the beginning, the users and sessions were being tracked, I don't know what happened.

Here is an image with a longer time range where it shows users and sessions. 
[image: Users and sessions]

Thanks

Comment: what are you passing to your `WindowsAppInitializer.InitializeAsync()` call? did you remove session as one of the items there?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that part.
I'm passing all Flags:
WindowsAppInitializer.InitializeAsync("-code-",WindowsCollectors.Metadata | WindowsCollectors.PageView | WindowsCollectors.Session | WindowsCollectors.UnhandledException);

Comment: have you changed how you create a `TelemetryClient` instance that you send your data with?  do you create a single static one somewhere and re-use it?  If you create that before the InitializeAsync work is done, it might not have session info configured there?  (I ran into this myself in my app, and changed my code to be inside `InitializeAsync(...).ContinueWith( t => { /* do stuff here */ }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyRanToCompletion);`

Comment: Was John Gardner's problem solved this problem for you? See Also [this blog](http://iziklisbon.com/2016/03/03/cant-see-users-and-sessions-in-ai/)

Comment: Thank you @JohnGardner, using ContinueWith did solve the problem.